# Share facebook page's post using Facebook Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I am creating an android app exclusive for my facebook page.
I am able to get the data from all posts.
I need to share one of the post in my timeline.

I am aware that sharing content is possible using ShareDialog but its available only for Links,Photo and Video.

Is it possible to share a specific fb post in my timeline like how we do in native facebook app using FB Android SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by using the 'link' element of the post result Json.

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(shareLink))
            .build();
```